# Facebook Graph API :: User accounts edge :: Not providing user accounts

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, permissions, account, empty-list

Disclaimer: this is not a April fool's day joke!

Since today, 01/April/2020, Facebook is not answering accounts edge on the user object.
I don't know if you guy's are experiencing the same.

I've tested in the v3.2 to v6.0 api version.

Here's my FG graph query:

/me?fields=id,name,accounts.limit(200){picture,name,access_token,instagram_business_account},email,location,locale,birthday,gender

If I run the query:

//accounts

I get nothing. Empty data.
I've confirmed that I have manage_pages permissions.

I'm alone here? 
Has anyone experience this issue?

Cheers,
Luis Teixeira

Comment: The second query should be read as:

/id/accounts

Comment: `manage_pages` permission does not automatically grant to access _all_ the user’s page any more, they get to select which ones to grant access to in the login dialog. Try and remove the permission (either via your user account settings, or the appropriate DELETE request), and then ask for it again. It should let you select the pages again then.

Comment: (I don’t currently see any such problems, it works fine in Graph API explorer, with multiple different app ids.)

Comment: Thanks @CBroe! I'm testing in the FB Graph API Explorer. I've refreshed the token and made sure that the FB Pages were selected and allowed to be used when I was refreshing the token. Yesterday was working fine. Today not. I'm one of the app developers.

Comment: I've opened a ticket in their support. Let's see.
If anyone has ideas, please, share. Or if you experience the same.

Comment: The issue in FB was marked as known issue. They are fixing it.
https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/254847062315419/

Comment: It was solved by FB.